# Is it possible to transparently kill & yank (copy & paste) org mode text with footnotes?

Tags: org-mode

When copying text with numbered footnote markers from one org-mode file to another, I have been manually copying and pasting the corresponding footnotes (sometimes renumbering them in the process).  This is difficult and error-prone.  Is there a way to have Org automatically copy and renumber the associated footnotes along with the main body text?

It seems like org-mode used to support inline footnotes (like LaTeX) which would be easier to copy and paste than numbered footnotes -- see the discussion archived at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-01/msg00004.html . But I don't think that feature exists in the current version.

If nothing like this exists, I might be motivated to add it myself, but I wanted to check first whether there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Footnotes) says that there are inline footnotes,as well as named footnotes, in addition to numbered footnotes:

> Org mode extends the number-based syntax to *named* footnotes and
>   optional inline definition.  Here are the valid references:
>
> ‘[fn:name]’
>        A named footnote reference, where ‘name’ is a unique label word,
>        or, for simplicity of automatic creation, a number.
>
> ‘[fn::This is the inline definition of this footnote]’
>        A LaTeX-like anonymous footnote where the definition is given
>        directly at the reference point.
>
> ‘[fn:name:a definition]’
>        An inline definition of a footnote, which also specifies a name for
>        the note.  Since Org allows multiple references to the same note,
>        you can then use ‘[fn:name]’ to create additional references.

Comment: Duh! I don't know how I missed this, but obviously I did. I still don't really want to use inline footnotes when editing, but it seems like I could get the behavior I want by advising the kill & yank commands to transform numbered footnotes into inline footnotes when copying/killing, then run `org-footnote-normalize` upon pasting/yanking.